# MERN Email Authentication Error for Backend API

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, express, mern

I'm trying to build email authentication with nodemailer.
I'm only just building the first part which is adding the functionality, however, I'm appending this to the API, I already built so appears I'm missing something. For example, my functioning API looks like this:

```
router.post("/register", async (req, res) => {
    const newUser = new User({
      fullname: req.body.fullname,
      email: req.body.email,
      position: req.body.position,
      username: req.body.fullname,

      password: CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(
        req.body.password,
        process.env.PASS_SEC
      ).toString(),
    });
  
    try {
      const savedUser = await newUser.save();
      res.status(201).json(savedUser);
    } catch (err) {
      res.status(500).json(err);
    }
  });
```

However i'm trying to add on email auth.

With this, I would like to add on the email auth, however it appears I don't recieve any emails.

Please see:

```
router.post("/register", async (req, res, transporter, EMAIL_SECRET) => {
    const newUser = new User({
      fullname: req.body.fullname,
      email: req.body.email,
      position: req.body.position,
      username: req.body.fullname,

      password: CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(
        req.body.password,
        process.env.PASS_SEC
      ).toString(),
    });


    // async email auth
    jwt.sign(
      {
        id: newUser._id, 
      },
      EMAIL_SECRET,
      {
        expiresIn:"1d",
      },
      (err, emailToken) => {
        const authUrl = `http://localhost:5000/confirmation/${emailToken}`;

        transporter.sendMail({
          to: this.arguments.email,
          subject: 'Confirmation Email',
          html: `Please click this email to confirm your email: <a href="${url}">${url}</a>`,
        });
      }
    )

    jwt.sign(
      {
        _id: _.pick(_id, 'id'),
      },
      EMAIL_SECRET,
      {
        expiresIn: '1d',
      },
      (err, emailToken) => {
        const url = `http://localhost:3000/confirmation/${emailToken}`;

        transporter.sendMail({
          to: args.email,
          subject: 'Confirm Email',
          html: `Please click this email to confirm your email: <a href="${url}">${url}</a>`,
        });
      },
    );

    try {

      const savedUser = await newUser.save();
      res.status(201).json(savedUser);
    } catch (err) {
      res.status(500).json(err);
    }
  });


//this authenticates it

  //User Email Auth Login
  router.get('/confirmation/:token', async (req, res) => {
    try {
      //verify the token with the secret
      const { user: { _id } } = jwt.verify(req.params.token, EMAIL_SECRET);
        await models.User.update({ confirmed: true }, { where: { _id } });
    } catch (e) {
      res.send('error');
    }

  });
```

Can someone please let me know what I'm missing? I'd love to have this functionality working!

I can confirm nodemailer details are correct :)

Comment: Did you check you spam folder?

Comment: yes Rohit I am using 10minute mail :)

Comment: In the first jwt.sign, you have "const authUrl" but in the email message/html, you're using "${url}"

Comment: Oh i just noticed you are using `${url}` not `authUrl` which was your variable name and `from: ` is also missing in object.

Comment: Also, in the first jwt.sign, you're using "this.arguments.email" and in the second one, you're using "args.email"